# Protocol buffer polymorphism

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a C++ program that sends out various events, e.g. `StatusEvent` and `DetectionEvent` with different proto message definitions to a message service (currently Active MQ, via activemq-cpp APU). I want to write a message listener that receives these messages, parses them and writes them to cout, for debugging purposes. The listener has `status_event_pb.h` and `detection_event_pb.h` linked.

My question is: How can I parse the received event without knowing its type? I want to do something like (in pseudo code)

```
receive event
type = parseEventType(event);
if( type == events::StatusEventType) { 
    events::StatusEvent se = parseEvent(event);
    // do stuff with se
}
else {
    // handle the case when the event is a DetectionEvent
}
```

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018743/whats-the-right-way-to-do-polymorphism-with-protocol-buffers) but I'm not sure if extensions are the right way to go here. A short code snippet pointing the way will be much appreciated. Examples on protobuf are so rare!

Thanks!

---

It seems extensions are indeed the way to go but I've got one last point to clear up. Here's the proto definition that I have so far:

```
// A general event, can be thought as base Event class for other event types.
message Event {
    required int64 task_id = 1;     
    required string module_name = 2;    // module that sent the event

    extensions 100 to 199;               // for different event types
}

// Extend the base Event with additional types of events.
extend Event {
    optional StatusEvent statusEvent = 100;
    optional DetectionEvent detectionEvent = 101;
}

// Contains one bounding box detected in a video frame, 
// representing a region of interest.
message DetectionEvent {
    optional int64 frame = 2;   
    optional int64 time = 4;
    optional string label = 6;
}

// Indicate status change of current module to other modules in same service.
// In addition, parameter information that is to be used to other modules can
// be passed, e.g. the video frame dimensions.
message StatusEvent {
    enum EventType { 
        MODULE_START = 1; 
        MODULE_END = 2; 
        MODULE_FATAL = 3; 
    }
    required EventType type = 1;        
    required string module_name = 2;    // module that sent the event

    // Optional key-value pairs for data to be passed on.
    message Data {
        required string key = 1;
        required string value = 2;
    }
    repeated Data data = 3; 
}
```

My problem now is (1) how to know which specific event that the Event message contains and (2) make sure that it contains only *one* such event (according to the definition, it can contain both a `StatusEvent` and a `DetectionEvent`).

Comment: Found this interesting thread: http://markmail.org/message/dgmf5iuhhgoe7keb#query:protocol%20buffer%20polymorphism+page:1+mid:73p5kddhvmokcpvo+state:results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the right way to do polymorphism with protocol buffers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3018743/1468366)

Answer (score 3):

I would not use Protocol Buffers for that, but that's perhaps a combination of little use and other habits.

Anyway, I think I would use an abstract class here, to ease general handling and to contain routing information. Class that would not be defined using protobuf, and would contain a protobuf message.

```
class Message
{
public:
  Type const& GetType() const;

  Origin const& GetOrigin() const;
  Destination const& GetDestination() const;

  // ... other informations

  template <class T>
  void GetContent(T& proto) const
  {
    proto.ParseFromIstream(&mContent); // perhaps a try/catch ?
  }

private:
  // ...

  std::stringstream mContent;
};
```

With this structure, you have both general and specific handling at the tip of your fingers:

```
void receive(Message const& message)
{
  LOG("receive - " << message.GetType() << " from " << message.GetOrigin()
                   << " to " << message.GetDestination());

  if (message.GetType() == "StatusEvent")
  {
    StatusEvent statusEvent;
    message.Decode(statusEvent);
    // do something
  }
  else if (message.GetType() == "DetectionEvent")
  {
    DetectionEvent detectionEvent;
    message.Decode(detectionEvent);
    // do something
  }
  else
  {
    LOG("receive - Unhandled type");
  }
}
```

Of course, it would be prettier if you used a `std::unordered_map<Type,Handler>` instead of a hardcoded `if / else if + / else` chain, but the principle remains identical:

1. Encode the type of message sent in the header
2. Decode only the header upon reception and dispatch based on this type
3. Decode the protobuf message in a part of the code where the type is known statically

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matthieu. Due to other constraints about the system I need to protobuf. As I learn more about this technology, the better it looks. I strongly recommend it.

Comment: @recipriversexclusion: what would we be without constraints :) ? Unfortunately I am not aware of an 'alternative' in the grammar itself. I suppose I would simply circumvent the problem by defining encoders/decoders that do not allow both to appear.