# Deserializing a Message multiple times with Google Protocol Buffers

Tags: polymorphism, protocol-buffers, message-passing

I am working with a system that is extremely modular. Messages can be determined by the by the 3-tuple of src, dest, type.

I'm looking into reimplementing our messages with Protocol Buffers. I've read through [Protocol buffer polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460869/protocol-buffer-polymorphism), [what's the right way to do polymorphism with protocol buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018743/whats-the-right-way-to-do-polymorphism-with-protocol-buffers) and http://www.indelible.org/ink/protobuf-polymorphism/

What I am wondering has anyone implement a solution where:

```
message header {
    required string src = 1
    required string dest = 2
    required string type = 3
}
```

And creating separate messages where:

```
message foo {
    required header h = 1
    required string a = 2
}
```

Separate file:

```
message bar {
    required header h = 1
    required uint32 num = 2
}
```

In the receiving code have something like:

```
Message.ParseFromString(msgStr)
if (Message.type == foo)
{
  FooMessage.ParseFromString(msgStr)
}
else {
    BarMessage.ParseFromString(msgStr)
}
```

If this approach has been used, is it better or worse than what's described in the above links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I found is to serialize/deserialize the message body as byte array. Then you will get needed level of abstraction:

```
message header {
    required string src = 1;
    required string dest = 2;
    required string type = 3;
}

message foo {
    required string a = 2;
}

message bar {
    required uint32 num = 2;
}

message request {
    required header h;
    required bytes data; // serialize foo or bar here
}
```

Then your code will be like that (this is a pseudo-code):

```
request req = request.ParseFromString(buffer);

if (req.h().type() == "foo") {
    foo msg = foo.ParseFromString(req.data);
    // process foo msg
}
else if (req.h().type() == "bar") {
    bar msg = bar.ParseFromString(req.data);
    // process bar msg
}
```