# Using protobuf enum value as a field number

Tags: enums, protocol-buffers

I'm wondering if it is possible to use Google Protocol Buffers' enum constants as a field number of other messages, like

```
enum Code {
  FOO = 100;
  BAR = 101;
}

message Message {
  required string foo = FOO;
}
```

This code doesn't work because `FOO`'s type is `enum Code` and only a number can be used as a field number.

I am trying to build polymorphic message definitions like this [animal example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000409/425943), that defines `Cat = 1;` in `enum Type` and `required Cat animal = 100;` as a unique extension number.

I thought it'd be nice to do

```
message Message {
  required string foo = FOO.value;
}
```

, so that I can ensure the uniqueness of the extension field number without introducing another magic number.

So the question: is it possible to refer an enum's integer value in the protocol buffer language?

Comment: As far as I know, simply: "no"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.  Sorry.

BTW, two enumerants of the same enum type can actually have the same numeric value, so defining these values in an enum does not actually ensure uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

With introduction to Protobuf oneof, this is now possible, as follows

```
message Animal
{    
    oneof Type
    {
        Cat cat = 101;
        Dog dog = 102;
    }
}

message Cat
{    
    // These fields can use the full number range.
    optional bool declawed = 1;
}

message Dog
{    
    // These fields can use the full number range.
    optional uint32 bones_buried = 1;
}
```